# Automatic Scrolling - not hardware related

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I have a problem and I hope someone here can help or direct me to the right place, any advice will be appreciated.

The problems I have are,

1. drop-down lists automatically scroll when I hover the mouse over them.
2. The browser window zooms out when I press ctrl.

**Important note.** This problem persists when either the mouse or keyboard is unplugged. So if i unplug my keyboard and hover the mouse over a drop-down menu then it scrolls automatically. On the other hand, if I unplug my mouse and press ctrl on a browser window the computer still zooms - that's why I concluded it is the operating system, but maybe I'm wrong. **The problem persists in the absence of hardware input.**

I have tried installing all the updates and upgraded to the latest version of Linux mint (this was after the problem began). Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help me.

Many thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same issue. "drop-down lists automatically scroll when I hover the mouse over them."
Anyone knows the solution for this...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418622)